# Istio. Who generates the initial Zipkin HTTP headers?

Tags: istio

in the documentation it is explained that your services have to resend a set of headers to enable pilot/Zipkin to correlate the information.

But who generates the first headers and set its values? The Istio Ingress controller?

How can I configure it, enable/disable it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Istio sidecar proxy (Envoy) generates the first headers. According to https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/latest/configuration/http_conn_man/headers#x-request-id:

> Envoy will generate an x-request-id header for all external origin requests (the header is sanitized). It will also generate an x-request-id header for internal requests that do not already have one.